# getting error in [R] - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, na

I am trying to step through a vector to find the outliers using IQR to calculate a range. When I run this script looking for values to the right of the IQR I get results and when I run to the left I get the error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. How can I scrub out the true and false in my dataset?
here is my script:

```
data = c(100, 120, 121, 123, 125, 124, 123, 123, 123, 124, 125, 167, 180, 123, 156)
Q3 <- quantile(data, 0.75) ##gets the third quantile from the list of vectors
Q1 <- quantile(data, 0.25) ## gets the first quantile from the list of vectors
outliers_left <-(Q1-1.5*IQR(data)) 
outliers_right <-(Q3+1.5*IQR(data))
IQR <- IQR(data)
paste("the innner quantile range is", IQR)
Q1 # quantil at 0.25
Q3 # quantile at 0.75
# show the range of numbers we have
paste("your range is", outliers_left, "through", outliers_right, "to determine outliers")
# count ho many vectors there are and then we will pass this value into a loop to look for 
# anything above and below the Q1-Q3 values
vectorCount <- sum(!is.na(data))
i <- 1
while( i < vectorCount ){
i <- i + 1
x <- data[i]
# if(x < outliers_left) {print(x)} # uncomment this to run and test for the left
if(x > outliers_right) {print(x)}
}
```

and the error I get is

```
[1] 167
[1] 180
[1] 156
Error in if (x > outliers_right) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

as you can see if you run this script, it is finding my 3 outliers on the right and also throws the error, but when I run this again on the left of my IQR, and I do have an outlier of 100 in the vector, I just get the error without other results being displayed.
How can I fix this script? any help greatly appreciated. I've been scouring the web and my books for days on how to fix this.

Comment: `i=16` makes the error. Switch `i<-i+1` after the comparison.

Comment: You're switching the location of that statement so that it occurs after the comparison.

Comment: You let `i` equal the length of the vector data before you add 1 and then index, hence it returns `NA` and `if` statement logical statement  fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the error is due to the way you've constructed your `while` loop. At the last iteration, `i == 16` though there are only 15 elements to process. Changing from `i <= vectorCount` to `i < vectorCount` fixes the problem:

```
i <- 1
while( i < vectorCount ){
  i <- i + 1
  x <- data[i]
  # if(x < outliers_left) {print(x)} # uncomment this to run and test for the left
  if(x > outliers_right) {print(x)}
}
#-----
[1] 167
[1] 180
[1] 156
```

However, this is really not how R works and you'll soon be frustrated at how long that code will take to run for any appreciable sized data. R is "vectorized" meaning that you can operate on all 15 elements of `data` at once. To print your outliers, I'd do this:

```
data[data > outliers_right]
#-----
[1] 167 180 156
```

Or to get all of them at once using the OR operator:

```
data[data< outliers_left | data > outliers_right]
#-----
[1] 100 167 180 156
```

For a little context, The above logical comparisons create a boolean value for each element of `data` and R only returns those that are TRUE. You can check this for yourself by typing:

```
data > outliers_right
#----
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

The `[` bit is actually an extraction operator, used to retrieve a subset of a data object. See the help page for some good background `?"["`.

Comment: I know that many people think that removing outliers is bad practice in statistics, but in the realm of field biology, removing outliers is needed to gain a better understanding of the "big picture"
Anyway - I found a much easier way to do this instead of

    data[data< outliers_left | data > outliers_right]

I found this to be more effective and it also allows me to pass the value onto other functions such as histograms and plots.

    x[!x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out]

Comment: @JohnP.Newbury - cool, good call on directly calling `boxplot.stats`. If you look at the source code for that function, you'll see it basically calls my answer above.

Comment: @JohnP.Newbury - also, for what it's worth - stackOverflow encourages you to answer your own question...and accept it if it's the "best answer" in your opinion...comments may be deleted/removed/or people may just not read them as much as the answers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The error message arises  because you you let `i <= vectorCount` so `i` can equal `vectorCount`, and thus  indexing `i = i+1` from data will give `NA`, and the `if` statement will fail.

If you want to find the outliers based on the IQR, you can use `findInterval`

```
outliers <- data[findInterval(data, c(Q1,Q3)) != 1]
```

I would also stop using `paste` to create character messages to be `printed`, use `message` instead.

Comment: thanks, I am new to R but modestly familiar with other languages so just finding my way through its nuances.